# Creating remote tracking branches using bash one-liner doesn't behave the same as running the commands manually

Tags: git, bash

If I run the following command:

```
for r in $(git branch -r | grep -Po "(?<=myremote/).*"); do echo git branch --track $r myremote/$r; done
```

I get the following output:

```
git branch --track foo myremote/foo
git branch --track bar myremote/bar
git branch --track baz myremote/baz
```

If I run these echoed commands individually, I get the following output:

```
Branch foo set up to track remote branch foo from myremote.
Branch bar set up to track remote branch bar from myremote.
Branch baz set up to track remote branch baz from myremote.
```

On the other hand, if I run the following one-liner (simply removing "echo"):

```
for r in $(git branch -r | grep -Po "(?<=myremote/).*"); do git branch --track $r myremote/$r; done
```

The branch creation fails with the following output:

```
fatal: 'foo' is not a valid branch name.
fatal: 'bar' is not a valid branch name.
fatal: 'baz' is not a valid branch name.
```

Why might this be happening, is there something different about the command that's being run? How can I debug this since?

UPDATE:

There appears to be some invisible control characters flowing through the unix pipe, even when I specify `--color=never` for `grep`. If I change the regex to `(?<=myremote/)[\w]*` the problem is solved. However, I still don't understand where the erroneous control character is coming from. If I add `echo $r | od -c` to the output to view raw data coming through the pipe, it's clear there are extra control characters there:

Output with original regex:

```
0000000   f   o   o 033   [   m  \n
0000007
```

Output with new regex:

```
0000000   f   o   o  \n
0000004
```

What is the extra character and where did it come from since I added the `--color=never` option?

Comment: It's probably something to do with the slashes. Try putting the two occurrences of `$r` in the git branch statements between double quotes.

Comment: Quotes don't seem to help. The same error occurs.

Comment: use `set -x` to see, what is going on.

Comment: The only difference is that there are single quotes around the branch names (e.g., `git branch --track 'foo' 'myremote/foo'` instead of `git branch --track foo myremote/foo`). Do you know why this might be the issue, and how to avoid it?

Comment: Not sure why it's happening, but one workaround would be to take your first loop (with the `echo`s) and do `for ... do echo ... | bash`, which will feed the output of your loop as input commands to a subshell...

Comment: this is the WRONG solution, which is why it's a comment not an answer: use `eval`.  Obviously running the commands you printed worked, so an extra resolve/execute step will "fix" the problem.  However, eval is a terrible thing unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git branch -r | grep -Po "(?<=myremote/).*"`? It looks like there is some kind of additional character or something.  Alternatively: `for r in $(git branch -r | grep -Po "(?<=myremote/).*"); do echo "$r:"; echo "$r" | md5sum; done`, which will give you checksums, which you can compare to the checksums of "foo", "bar", and "baz", to check for hidden characters.

Comment: The output of `git brance -r | grep -Po "(?<=myremote/).*"` is as expected, but colored pink. I realize coloring can cause problems sometimes because it is implemented via invisible terminal control characters, so I also tried the `--color=never` option to `grep` which still results in the the same fatal error, even though the color formatting is removed.

Comment: The output of `md5sum` is different from expected regardless of whether I use the `--color=never` option to grep. I tried this on a Mac (the problem is on Fedora) and the output of `md5sum` did match. Are there other invisible characters that may be causing a problem?

Comment: There seems to be an invisible or whitespace character at the end of the output of grep that is being matched by `'.*'`. If I spell out a whole branch name, the md5 matches. Is there an easy way to see such invisible characters?

Comment: Switching the regex to `(?<=myremote/)[\w]*` fixes the problem, but I still can't find out what the extra invisible character is. Is there a way to figure this out?

Comment: You already figured out that the three invisible characters are `033`   `[`   `m`; they might come from `git`, so that `grep` isn't responsible for them and its option `--color=never` has no effect. You can check this with `git branch -r|od -c`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine for me

```sh
git branch -r | awk '/myremote/{print $2}' FS=/ | while read q
do
  git branch --track $q myremote/$q
done
```